# Preg_match - checking alphanumeric

Tags: php, preg-match

I feel super fail asking this... but I've been trying to make sure my values are alphanumeric, and I can't do it!
    if(!preg_match("^[0-9]+:[a-zA-Z]+$/", $subuser)){
            $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric");
         }

I  did a search here and couldn't find anything... probably because this is so rudimentary =__=

Also, does anyone know of a resource (aside from PHP.net) that has a list of operators for Preg_match, and what they mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [ctype_alnum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) is better in this case.

For the operators : [official stuff](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to make sure they are alphanumeric,

```
if( preg_match(/\W/), $subuser) {  
  $form->setError($field, "* Username not alphanumeric"); 
}
```

will work (match any non-alphanumeric entry). But it looks like your username might require some structure.

I thought "Mastering Regular Expressions" was one of the better programming books I've read, and I've read at least a couple hundred by now.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1312676428&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124)

Comment: I wish I could show you but that snippet there will NOT work. You might have read a couple hundred books on RegEx, but you basic PHP knowlegde isn't as impressing.
Use `if(preg_match('/\w/', 'asd'))` instead!

Edit: I could have said that more friendly.